# Euler-Lagrange and Hamilton equations for $p$-forms

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

How are Euler-Lagrange equations and Hamilton equations modified (including higher order lagrangians) takinto into account $p$-forms?

I think it should also depend on the $D$-dimensional target spacetime manifold.

I presume there should be a pre-factor including the parity/grading before each term, but I don't know how to get the right prefactors heuristically.

Comment: To reopen this post (v2) consider to only ask 1 subquestion per post.

Comment: @Qmechanic take into account that IT can be made ONE question if you think in superspace p-forms terms...But I use to split questions in order to made them amendable...